# Problem accessing pymodbus from python3.12 on Raspberry 4 bullseye

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4, pymodbus

Running bullseye on a Raspberry 4 with python3.9.2 as default. Python programms with this default environment and pymodbus are working. Upgrading the default Python to python3.12 resulted in an error when using Thonny, which did not start any more with this version. So I returned to 3.9.2 as default and installed 3.12 as a second Python installation. 3.12, however, cannot find pymodbus, which is inside the 3.9.2 Python folder. So I get errors when trying to run programms using pymodbus from the 3.12 python environment.

Do I have to install pymodbus inside 3.12 as well? And if so how do I do this?
Or is there a way to tell 3.12 to use the pymodbus inside the 3.9.2 folder?
I am grateful for any hints.

Comment: In Bookworm comes with Python 3.11.

Comment: `Python 3.12` is very fresh version and some modules may not work - authors of modules may need time to modify modules. So better use `3.11` or `3.10`

Comment: Pythons don't share modules. Every Python version may need own modules (with small changes in code) - so you have to use `pip3.12` (or `python3.12 -m pip ...`) to install modules specially for `Python 3.12` And `pip3.9` (or `python3.9 -m pip ...`) to install for `Python 3.9`.

Comment: If original system was installed with `Python 3.9` then don't remove it because some elements in system may use it - and when you remove (or replace with other version) then system may not work.

Comment: @furas, thank you for your explanation. That answered my question.

Comment: see also similar portal for [Raspberry](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) and [forum Raspberry Pi](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/)